# PHP Ping script error 500

Tags: php, timeout, ping

Script is working but if host i try to ping not answer or get Request timed out i got error 500 from my server.

I should like solve this problem inside my php code if it is possible.

What i want is if host got timeout on ping then simply show "timeout" and not error from server.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" >
<?php
error_reporting(0); // Turn off all error reporting
?>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#222222">
        <center>
        <table width="100%" height="" border="1" cellpadding="3" style="color:black">
        <tr>     



<td align = center width="150"
<?php
function icmp_checksum($data) {
  if (strlen($data) % 2) {
    $data .= "\x00";
  }
  $bit = unpack('n*', $data);
  $sum = array_sum($bit);
  while  ($sum  >> 16) {
    $sum = ($sum >> 16) + ($sum & 0xffff);
  }
  return pack('n*', ~$sum);
}
function ping($host) {

  $tmp = "\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00PingTest";
  $checksum = icmp_checksum($tmp);
  $package = "\x08\x00".$checksum."\x00\x00\x00\x00PingTest";
  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
  socket_connect($socket, $host, null);
  $timer = microtime(1);
  socket_send($socket, $package, strlen($package), 0);
  if (socket_read($socket, 255)) {
    return round((microtime(1) - $timer) * 1000, 2);
  }
}

$host="telia.se";
$pingtime = ping ($host);

if ($pingtime == FALSE) 
    echo "bgcolor='red" ."' >"; 
else if ($pingtime > 40) 
    echo "bgcolor='yellow" ."' >"; 
else 
    echo "bgcolor='lime" ."' >";
echo ("<h2><B>$host</b></h2>");
echo $pingtime."ms";
?>
</td>

            </tr>
            </table>
            </center>
            </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What is your exact error?

Comment: Error 500
Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only returning a value if the ping succeeds. Update it to return a value when it fails:

```
if (socket_read($socket, 255)) {
    return round((microtime(1) - $timer) * 1000, 2);
} else {
    return false;
}
```